# Favicon.ico not changing when downloading

Tags: html, css

I'm brand new to html and CSS. I decided to use an icon as my favicon, so I used a generator to change my .png to a .ico. I downloaded it, used it, was great. Now I want to change it, but I'm running into an issue.
[What I want as my favicon.ico](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ljkrh.png)

Very hard to see, but it is a circle with a logo in it.

When I move it to my website folder, it changes to THIS:
[The logo it changes too](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9DbU.jpg)

It changes when I move it. Granted these are .png, but I use the .ico of both those pictures. Tried using a different .ico converter, didn't work. Tried perm deleting the first .ico, didn't work. If anyone has any ideas, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The most likely is that it is not changing due browser caching.
Clear your browser cache or when you specify the url add a parameter you can change when you want a new version downloaded.

```
href=”favicon.ico?v=1”
```

Comment: LIFESAVER. Thanks!!